# How to authenticate the primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, ruby-on-rails-3

i can't authenticate the `Transaction_Id` where this is the primary key of my transaction table, while i can do it with the `email`. what would seem to be the problem? help. thanks.

here's my model/transaction:

```
def self.authenticate(email, transaction_id)
    user = Transaction.find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.Transaction_Id
      return user
    else
      return false
    end
end
```

here's my controller/modifications:

```
  def attempt_login
    user = Transaction.authenticate(params[:email], params[:Transaction_Id])
    if user
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        session[:email] = user.email
        flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in!"
        redirect_to :action => "modify"
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password  combination."
        redirect_to :action => "login"
    end
  end
```

and here's my view/login:

```
<div class="login">
    <%= form_tag :action => "attempt_login" do %>

        <%= label_tag :email, "Email Address:" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :email %>
        <%= label_tag :Transaction_Id, "Transaction Id:" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :Transaction_Id %>

        <%= submit_tag "Log In"%>   
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by authenticate primary key? Do you mean validating it? Second of all, what's the problem? Is an error occurring? If so post the log output. What is exactly not working correctly?

Comment: there is no error. but i cannot validate the Transaction_Id. if i enter a correct email and wrong transaction_id, it can access..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check only if there is a transaction_id present in your found user object, but you do not compare this id to the given id, so try:

```
def self.authenticate(email, transaction_id)
    user = Transaction.find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.Transaction_Id == transaction_id
      return user
    else
      return false
    end
end
```

or (don't know if it works)

```
def self.authenticate(email, transaction_id)
    user = Transaction.find_by_email_and_transaction_id(email, transaction_id)
    if user
      return user
    else
      return false
    end
end
```

in short:

```
# will return user if found; else nil
def self.authenticate(email, transaction_id)
    Transaction.find_by_email_and_transaction_id(email, transaction_id)
end
```

Comment: What are your changes since then? Do you have tests for this to make sure no other side effects are influencing?

Comment: i forgot to put '.to_d' on my model.. sorry. my bad. btw, thanks! :)